# Reading a angularjs promise object?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a service that returns a study object as shown:

```
$scope.study = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier});
```

When I print out the study object using:

```
console($scope.study);
```

I get this message on the chrome console:

```
Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query:     
function...}
```

So how do I read this study object. I like to be able to print its contents. For instance study has an id, and a list of cases. I like to be able to print:

```
console.log(study.id);
console.log(study.cases.length);
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: show yo code. You should make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that since you are receiving a promise as a response from your service you are using 'ngResource'. If so, then here is some documentation on using that module and how to handle the objects it returns.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

For your example though, you would need to just do the following

```
StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier}).$promise.then(function(study) {
  $scope.study = study;
});
```

Hope this helps!